# What does "convergence" mean for Thinning?

Tags: image-processing

I've been using `Thinning` recently on line-like structures in an attempt to generate skeleton-like chains of pixels connected through their Moore neighborhoods.

The description of `Thinning` says that the algorithm "finds the skeletons of foreground regions in image by applying morphological thinning until convergence".  What does "convergence" mean?  If I start with a cluster of pixels connected through their Moore neighborhoods, what am I guaranteed after "convergence"?  Will the product always be a chain of pixels also connected through their Moore neighborhoods?

Comment: Off-topic on this site, I'm afraid. I do not see how it pertains to _Mathematica_.

Comment: @Sasha You have a valid point with respect to my comment about "implementing Thinning in other languages", and I deleted this comment.  I didn't mean it in the sense of "I want to rewrite the procedure in C, etc." but more of a "what's going on here?" remark.  However, I would argue that this question is on-topic here since it's directly asking about the behavior of a particular Mathematica function for image processing, and what the description of that function means?

Comment: @Sasha I've also changed the title to better focus the question for the purpose I claim.

Answer (score 3):

The thinning operation become [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) after a number of iterations, which means the result does not change anymore - in other word, the algorithm have converged to a solution.